# Character count in Java

Tags: java

consider this code:
package q2b;

```
public class Q2b {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String kalimat = new String("Sue sells sea shells on the seashore!");
        String upperLetter = "";
        String removeLetter = "";

        //Code to count the spacing in the string
        for (int i = 0; i < kalimat.length(); i++) {
            if (kalimat.charAt(i) == 's') {
                upperLetter += 'S';
            } else {
                upperLetter += kalimat.charAt(i);

            }

        }
        System.out.println("The letter modification in the string are :" + upperLetter);
    }
}
```

My Question:
what code should I type to get how many lowercase letter 's' has been replace?

Comment: Don't mix up `Java` and `JavaScript` there's a huge difference.

Comment: Concatenating `String` in a loop? Why?

Answer (score 3):

Add this:

```
int count = 0; // <-- here

for (int i = 0; i < kalimat.length(); i++) {
    if (kalimat.charAt(i) == 's') {
        upperLetter += 'S';
        count++; // <-- and here
    } else {
        upperLetter += kalimat.charAt(i);

    }

}
```

In the end you will have the number of substitutions in the variable `count`.

Comment: You should declare count's type.

Comment: Thank you, I was mislead in believing it was Javascript... ok, in JS you still should declare variables so that's no excuse :)

Comment: It can compile now, and it has 7 's' lowercase has been replaced.
:)

Answer (score 2):

Declare and initialize an `int` variable to 0 outside the processing loop. Increment it while processing whenever you replace a `s` with an `S`.

As a side note, it is obviously out of the scope of this question, but using the `+` operator for repetitive String concatenation is highly inefficient. You should use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding about your question, the below code may help you,

Declared a variable 'count' and it will increase in the presence of each lowercase letter 's' in the  iteration.

```
public class Q2b {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String kalimat = new String("Sue sells sea shells on the seashore!");
    String upperLetter = "";
    String removeLetter = "";
       int count=0; 
    //Code to count the spacing in the string
    for (int i = 0; i < kalimat.length(); i++) {
        if (kalimat.charAt(i) == 's') {
            upperLetter += 'S';
            count++;
        } else {
            upperLetter += kalimat.charAt(i);

        }

    }
    System.out.println("The letter modification in the string are :" + upperLetter);
    System.out.println("Number of lower case letter 's' is :" + count);
  }
 }
```